# How to get a div content and place the outcome in php

Tags: php

I am new to php i was wondering if anyone can help me basically i have been assigned to create a database where you have four questions and four answers and the database should display the four questions and when you click on the button it would say "incorrect" or "correct" on the database if this makes sense here is my html code but I have no idea on how get php to place it into the database, i tried to use Div/ID tags to help but i haven't got a clue what i am doing

```
<img src="Images/Question1.png" usemap="#mainMap" id="main" style="position:absolute;display:none;left:0px;top:0px;" border="0" />
<map name="mainMap" id="mainMap">
  <div id="Incorrectanswer1"><area shape="rect" coords="82,192,196,242" onclick="incorrectAnswer()" /></div>
  <div id="Incorrectanswer2"><area shape="rect" coords="83,254,197,300" onclick="incorrectAnswer()" /></div>
  <div id="Incorrectanswer3"><area shape="rect" coords="83,310,201,368" onclick="incorrectAnswer()" /></div>
  <div id="Correctanswer1"><area shape="rect" coords="84,373,205,430" onclick="correctAnswer()" /></div>
</map>
```

if anyone could help or point me in the right direction this would be helpful.

Comment: php works with forms (`<form>`, `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<button>`), not divs with IDs... See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Comment: I'd suggest you start by learning the basics of PHP/forms/databases. This is not something that can be *answered* in a single answer.

Comment: Okay I understand more clearly on the process, someone recommended using (href, where you set answer=[in]correct as a URL parameter) but i have no idea on what to do, I also got recommended to use AJAX or the GET/POST any suggestions on where to go from this?

Comment: It's pretty pointless to have the in/correct marker for the answer on the client side. Anybody bothering to look at the URL and/or HTML source can answer the question without knowing the answer. No, you submit *an* answer to the server (e.g. "answer id 42"), usually via a form and POST, and the server checks whether the answer was correct.

Answer (score 1):

As some people has suggested you should change the way this is designed.

HTML/Javascript is client side and a simple right-click -> show source can tell any user which is the correct answer. So what is the correct way to do it? well there are some, let me explain one of them:

Your HTML part is fine, but the `onclick` part should be changed to a new function called `check_answer(id)` for example, you pass the answer `id` to that function, then it will be submited to a PHP that will check it display a text telling the user if the answer was correct or not.

One way to do this would be AJAX, but let's try one more simple:

```
<form id="answer_send" name="answer_send" action="check_answer.php" method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" id="answer_id" />
</form>
```

This HTML can be inserted in any part of the body, it won't be displayed anyway. Then we need the new javascript function 'check_answer(id)':

```
function check_answer(id){
    document.getElementById('answer_id').value=id;
    document.forms["answer_send"].submit();
}
```

Then in the `check_answer.php`:

```
$id=$_POST['answer_id'];

if($id > 0){
     //do something to compare the answer
     if(answer_ok(id)){
         echo "Correct Answer!";
     }else{
         echo "Incorrect Answer!";
     }
}
```

What's the problem here? the user would get redirected to another page, so if you want to display multiple questions/answers and check them without sending the user to another URL you should use AJAX. The only difference when doing this process with AJAX would be that there's no need for a form, and the `check_answer(id)` function would have to do the AJAX call and display a message to the user depending on the return value of the AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks for your post I used your code to see if it would work but now when I try and click on it nothing happens any ideas?